# How to filter rows using custom function in pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, pyarrow

I've a parquet dataset that contains latitude and longitude values as separate columns. And I want to filter those rows that are inside a polygon, I'm able to do this in pandas dataframe but unable to do in pyarrow table.

I'm using pyarrow to read the parquet files, as it's quite fast.

Here's how I'm doing this in pandas:

```
import pyarrow as pa
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point

def point_in_polygon(df, polygon): 
    return df.apply(lambda x: shape(polygon).intersects(Point(x.lon, x.lat)), axis=1)

res: pa.Table = ParquetDataset(....)
res.to_pandas().loc[lambda df: point_in_polygon(df, polygon)]
```

But the problem with above approach is that it's quite slow. I know of filters in pyarrow and pyarrow.compute but unable to figure out how I can achieve this.

If more information is needed please let me know :) 
Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @cicada_, I shared some ideas below hoping they can help. If you are able to share an example of your data, then I can build a code example of using Polars for it

Comment: Can you turn all the checks in `shape(polygon).intersects(Point(x.lon, x.lat))` into calls to simple compute kernels returning boolean arrays then applying AND/OR to the resulting boolean arrays?

You can improve the perf of your current version by moving `shape(polygon)` outside the lambda as well.

Comment: Hi @philix, Thanks for the suggestion there's is a way to pass mask (boolean array) to filter rows in pyarrow but I'm unable to figure out an efficient way to get this array.

Comment: Hi @Luca, Thanks for your time. For now I was able to work with A. Coady's solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's slow because of Python function calls looped over scalar points. Shapely supports [universal functions](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#what-is-a-ufunc) on numpy arrays. The key is to get an array of points with the loop in-lined. Assuming you have arrays (numpy or pyarrow) of `lons` and `lats`.

```py
points = shapely.from_ragged_array(shapely.GeometryType.POINT, np.array([lons, lats]).T)
shape(polygon).intersects(points)
```

Comment: Thank you!, I'll try using this :)